# Unauthoriezed Access Exception

Tags: c#, exception, io

i have a cloud database server like application on my computer that i'm hosting my game on. However, every time an user tries to save data i get an UnauthorizedAccessException.
Im running it by admin and i dont have any specias right in my folder so i have no idea what's the problem.
Here's my code:

```
public const string root = "D:/DATABASE/";
public static void WriteData(string playername, string type, string data)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("D:/DATABASE/" + playername))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("D:/DATABASE/" + playername);
        Directory.CreateDirectory("D:/DATABASE/" + playername + "/weapons");
    }
    if (type != "Weapon")
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:/DATABASE/" + playername + "/" + type + ".sav"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string[] dat = data.Split('%');
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:/DATABASE/" + playername + "/weapons/" + dat[0] + ".gfa"))
        {
            string[] lines = dat[1].Split('@');
            foreach (string cline in lines)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(cline);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static string ReadLoadout(string playername)
{
    string output = "";
    string[] items = new string[2];
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(root + playername + "/loadout.gfl"))
    {
        items[0] = sr.ReadLine();
        items[1] = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    int c = 0;
    foreach (string citem in items)
    {
        if (c > 0) output += "$";
        output += citem + "%" + GetCompressedWeaponFile(playername, citem);
        c++;
    }
    return output;
}

public static string GetCompressedWeaponFile(string playerName, string weaponName)
{
    string output = "";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(root + playerName + "/weapons/" + weaponName))
    {
        string line = " ";
        int c = 0;
        while (line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                if (c > 0) output += "@";
                output += line;
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
public static void RegisterNewUser(string username, string password, string email)
{
    string udir = root + username;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(udir);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(udir + "/weapons");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(udir + "/loadouts");
    File.WriteAllText(udir + "/password.sav", password);
    File.WriteAllText(udir + "/level.sav", "1");
    File.WriteAllText(udir + "/money.sav", "1000");
    File.WriteAllText(udir + "/email.sav", email);
    File.WriteAllText(udir + "/loadout.gfl", "");
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(root + "emails.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(email);
    }
    Email.Send(email, "New Account Registration", string.Format(mailTemplate, username, password));
}
public static void EditLoadout(string username, string items)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(root + username + "/loadout.gfl",items.Split('#'));
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated the question to indicate which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Try creating file or directory at specified location and find out whether you have rights or not?

Comment: I have full right to the directory. ANd i have no idea wich line is it as doesnt show one in my code (it does in C# libraries code). Actually sometims it works but mostly it will fail

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide specific help without more information. Here are a few of troubleshooting suggestions:

1) Try running your code on a different machine. Specifically your development computer. Do you still have the same error? If not, then there is indeed a permission problem.

2) Have you tried checking the stack trace of the exception?

When you run the application on your own computer, try using the IDE to display the exception. Yes, the problem may ultimately be in a low-level class, but you should be able to break on the error and go back in the call stack to see which method in your code is actually throwing the error.

3) Check the actual exception, even for a system-level exception.

Chances are, if you are able to debug this in the IDE, that you will see property information that will give you a hint.  Is it in a directory method or a file write method? Check additional properties.  Somewhere it might give you the text of the path (assuming it's a file issue) that it failed on that that could help narrow things down too.

4) Add Exception handling to your code

This is a good rule of thumb, and you should really do this anyway to make a stronger program. Regardless of who's method you are calling (yours, someone else's, or a system method) you need to determine where it should be handled.

For example, in your code, in the RegisterNewUser() method, consider something like:

```
 public static void RegisterNewUser(string username, string password, string email)
{
    try
    {
        string udir = root + username;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(udir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(udir + "/weapons");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(udir + "/loadouts");
        File.WriteAllText(udir + "/password.sav", password);
        File.WriteAllText(udir + "/level.sav", "1");
        File.WriteAllText(udir + "/money.sav", "1000");
        File.WriteAllText(udir + "/email.sav", email);
        File.WriteAllText(udir + "/loadout.gfl", "");
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(root + "emails.txt", true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(email);
        }
        Email.Send(email, "New Account Registration", string.Format(mailTemplate, username, password));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Create a method to display or log the exception, with it's own error handler
        LogAndDisplayExceptions(ex);
        // Send the user a message that we failed to add them. Put this in it's own try-catch block
        // ideally, for readability, in it's own method.

        try
        {
            Email.Send(email, "Failed to register", "An error occurred while trying to add your account.");
        }
        catch (Exception exNested)
        {
            LogAndDisplayExceptions(exNested);
        }
    }
}
```

5) Add a "crash-and-burn" exception handler to "main"
In the method that is your "top method" (it's hard to tell in the snippet you provided since there are few methods that would attempt to write to the disk) you could wrap your code in a try - catch block and print the exception or write it to disk.

If you have having trouble writing the exception to disk, I would suggest creating an error file first, make sure that the user account that is running the program can write to it, and then in the catch block open the file for APPEND. This should make it easier to get to the error text.

6) When all else fails, use the Debug class or Console class to write the traditional "I made it to line x."

While this will not solve your problem, it should help you get more information that will provide more insight into where your code is causing an error.

Comment: really thanks i'll try that but the registration works totally fine. Im getting problems with data laoding/saving